Extra Post In Flatlist At The End
export default function AboutScreen({ route }) {

const [postList,setPostList] = useState([''])


    const { name } = route.params;


    const [ text, setText ] = useState('');
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(
                'https://cookiebytes.ca/google-login-php/Jacob11.php?name=' + name
            );

            const data = await response.text()
            const split = data.split('||');
            const text = response.text()
            console.log(data)
            setPostList(split)

        }
        useEffect(() => {
            fetchData();
        }, []);

    onLight = (selectedVariable: string) => {
        // Your logic for function 1
        console.log(selectedVariable)
        AsyncStorage.setItem('any_key_herCreative', selectedVariable)
        navigation.navigate("Pix||", {
            name: selectedVariable})

    }



    return (
            <FlatList
                            data={postList}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                                return (
                                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ () => handleClick(item)}>
                                            <Card.Cover
                                                source={{ uri: 'https://www.cookiebytes.ca/google-login-php/' + item}}
                                                theme={{
                                                    roundness: 0,
                                                    isV3: false,
                                                }}
                                            />
                                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
             )
            }}
          />
        );
    }

Extra post appears at end of flatlist
I'll post Php when I can It just wont allow for smooth scrolling effect with an extra post at the end of each flatlist! If anyone can help would be greatly appreciated!
